# Get email from personal information from User Object?

Tags: oauth2, jsforce

I need to fetch email of the user which they place under personal information but I seem to be getting back all the contact's emails of the user.

[image]

So for the above example, I need `user@abc.ai`. My code and query is as follows:

```
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        instanceUrl: ...,
        accessToken:...,
        refreshToken: ...,
        oauth2: {
            "clientId": ...,
            "clientSecret": ...,
            "redirectUri": ...
        },
    });

const query = "Select  Email FROM User";
const result = await conn.query(query);
```

But I do not get this email, I get all the contacts email in an array which is like 100+ in length.

Comment: You need a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning every user in the database. You need to limit the query to just the current user.

You should call the `identity()` method, and then you can query the user:

```
con.identity((err, res) => {
  if(res) {
    let result = conn.query(`select email from user where id = '${res.user_id}'`);
  }
});
```

Or, you can use Chatter:

```
conn.chatter.resource('/users/me').retrieve((err, res) => {
  let email = res.email;
});
```